# How can I select the row with the highest ID in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

How can I select the row with the highest ID in MySQL? This is my current code:

```
SELECT * FROM permlog WHERE max(id)
```

Errors come up, can someone help me?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM permlog ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1
```

Comment: why LIMIT 0, 1 and not LIMIT 1?

Comment: No particular reason, both LIMIT 1 and LIMIT 0,1 are valid.  Although it shows you can SELECT * FROM permlog LIMIT 1,1 to get the 2nd highest.

Comment: Too bad the same approach doesn't apply to JOIN'd on tables.

Comment: `LIMIT 0,1` and `LIMIT 1` does the same thing. The first one includes offset for the row limit. (skip 0, get the following 1)

Comment: This approach is not good when we have inner queries. As mysql does not support limit functionality in inner query. Thus, Answer given by Mohammad Khan is vaid

Answer (score 43):

if it's just the highest ID you want. and ID is unique/auto_increment:

```
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tablename
```

Comment: Actually that's the only correct answer! Adding `LIMIT 1`would make it perfect I think...

Comment: @Sliq Actually it only returns 1 row (or 1 value), so LIMIT 1 is redundant!

Comment: As a point of interest, in a small table, the `MAX` method is actually about 2 times slower in my context (iOS sqlite driven by Flutter driver sqflite) than using the select. No idea how it scales, though.

Answer (score 24):

For MySQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM permlog
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

You want to sort the rows from highest to lowest `id`, hence the `ORDER BY id DESC`. Then you just want the first one so [`LIMIT 1`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html):

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement.
>   [...]
>   With one argument, the value specifies the number of rows to return from the beginning of the result set

Answer (score 20):

```
SELECT *
FROM permlog
WHERE id = ( SELECT MAX(id) FROM permlog ) ;
```

This would return all rows with highest `id`, in case `id` column is not constrained to be unique.

Comment: Sorry, mixed up this answer with another question. Thus the downvote. It's locked, can't change my vote. Please edit it so I may upvote it.

Comment: How to use the same statement with one more condition like `AND (isVerified = 1)` for example

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT MAX(id)  FROM  TABLENAME`

This identifies the largest id and returns the value

Comment: this will actually only show the max value - could you also point out how to use it with nested query? Also put code in "code"

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have mulitple record for same date or leave_type but different id and you want the maximum no of id for same date or leave_type as i also sucked with this issue, 
so Yes you can do it with the following query:

```
select * from tabel_name where employee_no='123' and id=(
   select max(id) from table_name where employee_no='123' and leave_type='5'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tablename LIMIT 1
```

Use this query to find the highest ID in the MySQL table.

Comment: LIMIT 1 is not needed: The max element is only one

Answer (score 1):

Since both `SELECT MAX(id) FROM table` and `SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1` fulfill the goal, the interesting part is, which performs better.

`SELECT MAX(id) FROM table`: 152ms
`SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1`: 25ms
(InnoDB-table with 55M rows on MySQL 8.0, 10 runs, average result)

Of course thats not representive, but gives an idea, that the ORDER BY method performs significantly better.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only proposed method who actually selects the whole row, not only the max(id) field. It uses a subquery

SELECT * FROM  permlog WHERE id = ( SELECT MAX( id ) FROM permlog )

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `permlog` as one
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) as max_id FROM `permlog`) as two 
ON one.id = two.max_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This Query is to get the max id +1 of Table Record So we can show the Current Record Number.

> SELECT MAX(Emp_ID)+1 AS Emp_IDMax from employee_master

[Screen Shot of MaxID Record mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beBFs.png)

If Any One to know the highest Number Of Table Record MaxID Only then go with Following Query for mysql

> SELECT MAX(Emp_ID) AS Emp_IDMax from employee_master