# How do I get column with the highest ID from a sql database table?

Tags: sql

I have a table orders with many orders in it,every order has an unique ID. I need to get the column with highest ID,if you know how to do that please help.
thx!

Comment: What means you need to get the "column" with highest ID? Show your query.

Comment: I mean to get column that has highest ID in Table Orders
"select * from Orders where ID is highest"

Comment: @G.D: so you want the row with the highest ID not the column? Have you searched before you have asked this? There are plenty of duplicates like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881424/how-can-i-select-the-row-with-the-highest-id-in-mysql) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604893/sql-select-row-from-table-where-id-maxid) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column).

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
select yourcolumn from yourtable where id=(select max(id) from yourtable )
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT top 1 yourColumn FROM yourTable ORDER BY yourId DESC
```

They key points here are TOP and ORDER BY

Depending on the RDMS you are using you may have to use different flavours of TOP but the principle is the same....

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-top-clause.htm

Comment: OP hasn't even mentioned the rdbms but you presume sql-server