# Why my SELECT statement returned 2 rows when SELECT MAX(ID)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select only max(ID) row , when i select direct max(ID) by using this SELECT its working correct and return max(ID) one row with maximum ID

```
select max(id)
FROM [LAB_CULTURE_RESULT]
      where order_id = 1900001265 
     and testid = 1100
```

but when i use the other SELECT statement with more details its not working and returns all the rows 4 rows not only max(id) row 
this is my select statement how to use max(id) and return one row only

```
SELECT MAX([ID])
      ,[SAMPLE_ID]
      ,[ORDER_ID]
      ,[TESTID]
      ,[SAMPLE_STATUS]
      ,[EXAMINED_BY]
      ,[EXAMINED_DATE]
      ,[APPROVED_BY]
      ,[APPROVED_DATE]
      ,[RESULT_NOTE]
      ,[MACHINE_ID]
      ,[DEPTID]
      ,[PATIENT_NO]
      ,[CUSTID]
      ,[REQ_FORM_NO]
      ,[PC_FILENO]
      ,[CULTURE_REPORT]
      ,[SAMPLE]
      ,[PUS_CELLS]
      ,[RED_CELLS]
      ,[YEAST_CELLS]
      ,[CLUE_CELLS]
      ,[RESULT_POSITIVE]
      ,[AMIKACIN]
      ,[AZTREONAM]
      ,[AMOXIXILLIN]
      ,[AMPICILLIN]
      ,[AMOXICLAV]
      ,[AZITHROMYCIN]
      ,[CEFIXIME]
      ,[CEFACLOR]
      ,[CEPHRADINE]
      ,[CEFTAZIDIME]
      ,[CEFUROXIME]
      ,[CEFOTAXIME]
      ,[CLINDAMYCIN]
      ,[CIPROFLOXACIN]
      ,[CLARITHROMYCIN]
      ,[CEFADROXIL]
      ,[CEFTRIAXONE]
      ,[TEICOPLANIN]
      ,[CEFEPIME]
      ,[CEFOXITIN]
      ,[GENTAMICIN]
      ,[LEVOFLOXACIN]
      ,[NORFLOXACIN]
      ,[OXACILLIN]
      ,[CARBENICILLIN]
      ,[PIPERACILLIN]
      ,[PEFLOXACIN]
      ,[TETRACYCLIN]
      ,[PENICILLIN]
      ,[VANCOMYCIN]
      ,[VIABLE_COLONY_COUNT]
      ,[UPDATED_BY]
      ,[UPDATED_DATE]
  FROM [LAB_CULTURE_RESULT]
  where order_id = 1900001265 
 and testid = 1100
group by [SAMPLE_ID]
      ,[ORDER_ID]
      ,[TESTID]
      ,[SAMPLE_STATUS]
      ,[EXAMINED_BY]
      ,[EXAMINED_DATE]
      ,[APPROVED_BY]
      ,[APPROVED_DATE]
      ,[RESULT_NOTE]
      ,[MACHINE_ID]
      ,[DEPTID]
      ,[PATIENT_NO]
      ,[CUSTID]
      ,[REQ_FORM_NO]
      ,[PC_FILENO]
      ,[CULTURE_REPORT]
      ,[SAMPLE]
      ,[PUS_CELLS]
      ,[RED_CELLS]
      ,[YEAST_CELLS]
      ,[CLUE_CELLS]
      ,[RESULT_POSITIVE]
      ,[AMIKACIN]
      ,[AZTREONAM]
      ,[AMOXIXILLIN]
      ,[AMPICILLIN]
      ,[AMOXICLAV]
      ,[AZITHROMYCIN]
      ,[CEFIXIME]
      ,[CEFACLOR]
      ,[CEPHRADINE]
      ,[CEFTAZIDIME]
      ,[CEFUROXIME]
      ,[CEFOTAXIME]
      ,[CLINDAMYCIN]
      ,[CIPROFLOXACIN]
      ,[CLARITHROMYCIN]
      ,[CEFADROXIL]
      ,[CEFTRIAXONE]
      ,[TEICOPLANIN]
      ,[CEFEPIME]
      ,[CEFOXITIN]
      ,[GENTAMICIN]
      ,[LEVOFLOXACIN]
      ,[NORFLOXACIN]
      ,[OXACILLIN]
      ,[CARBENICILLIN]
      ,[PIPERACILLIN]
      ,[PEFLOXACIN]
      ,[TETRACYCLIN]
      ,[PENICILLIN]
      ,[VANCOMYCIN]
      ,[VIABLE_COLONY_COUNT]
      ,[UPDATED_BY]
      ,[UPDATED_DATE]
```

Comment: Why do you have a `group by` clause in your query? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: When using max function you have to use group by with other columns in select statement.

Comment: So stop using `max`. Again, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @melpomene , i have laboratory system results and results updated more than one time i want to get last updated result in laboratory results to print last updated result.

Comment: why you give -1 ? what is wrong ?

Comment: As per your system I recommend to make a scalar function and use that function to get the maximum id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because what you're doing isn't the "right" answer. Here are a couple of alternatives:

```
--Using a CTE:
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT [ID]
        ,[SAMPLE_ID]
        ,[ORDER_ID]
        ,[TESTID]
        ,[SAMPLE_STATUS]
        ,[EXAMINED_BY]
        ,[EXAMINED_DATE]
        ,[APPROVED_BY]
        ,[APPROVED_DATE]
        ,[RESULT_NOTE]
        ,[MACHINE_ID]
        ,[DEPTID]
        ,[PATIENT_NO]
        ,[CUSTID]
        ,[REQ_FORM_NO]
        ,[PC_FILENO]
        ,[CULTURE_REPORT]
        ,[SAMPLE]
        ,[PUS_CELLS]
        ,[RED_CELLS]
        ,[YEAST_CELLS]
        ,[CLUE_CELLS]
        ,[RESULT_POSITIVE]
        ,[AMIKACIN]
        ,[AZTREONAM]
        ,[AMOXIXILLIN]
        ,[AMPICILLIN]
        ,[AMOXICLAV]
        ,[AZITHROMYCIN]
        ,[CEFIXIME]
        ,[CEFACLOR]
        ,[CEPHRADINE]
        ,[CEFTAZIDIME]
        ,[CEFUROXIME]
        ,[CEFOTAXIME]
        ,[CLINDAMYCIN]
        ,[CIPROFLOXACIN]
        ,[CLARITHROMYCIN]
        ,[CEFADROXIL]
        ,[CEFTRIAXONE]
        ,[TEICOPLANIN]
        ,[CEFEPIME]
        ,[CEFOXITIN]
        ,[GENTAMICIN]
        ,[LEVOFLOXACIN]
        ,[NORFLOXACIN]
        ,[OXACILLIN]
        ,[CARBENICILLIN]
        ,[PIPERACILLIN]
        ,[PEFLOXACIN]
        ,[TETRACYCLIN]
        ,[PENICILLIN]
        ,[VANCOMYCIN]
        ,[VIABLE_COLONY_COUNT]
        ,[UPDATED_BY]
        ,[UPDATED_DATE],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC) AS RN
    FROM [LAB_CULTURE_RESULT]
    WHERE order_id = 1900001265 
    AND testid = 1100)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;

--Using TOP 1 WITH TIES:
SELECT  TOP 1 WITH TIES
        [ID]
        ,[AZITHROMYCIN]
        ,[CEFIXIME]
        ,[CEFACLOR]
        ,[CEPHRADINE]
        ,[CEFTAZIDIME]
        ,[CEFUROXIME]
        ,[CEFOTAXIME]
        ,[CLINDAMYCIN]
        ,[CIPROFLOXACIN]
        ,[CLARITHROMYCIN]
        ,[CEFADROXIL]
        ,[CEFTRIAXONE]
        ,[TEICOPLANIN]
        ,[CEFEPIME]
        ,[CEFOXITIN]
        ,[GENTAMICIN]
        ,[LEVOFLOXACIN]
        ,[NORFLOXACIN]
        ,[OXACILLIN]
        ,[CARBENICILLIN]
        ,[PIPERACILLIN]
        ,[PEFLOXACIN]
        ,[TETRACYCLIN]
        ,[PENICILLIN]
        ,[VANCOMYCIN]
        ,[VIABLE_COLONY_COUNT]
        ,[UPDATED_BY]
        ,[UPDATED_DATE]
FROM [LAB_CULTURE_RESULT]
WHERE order_id = 1900001265 
AND testid = 1100
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC);
```

Note that if you are expecting more than 1 row (maybe the "last" row per `order_id`) you'll need to add a `PARTITION BY` clause to the `OVER` for the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

Comment: Thank you i tried WITH CTE its working fine i will try the other solutions also

Answer (score 2):

It works exactly as it must.

It returns quantity of rows equal to distinct values of fields in `GROUP BY`.

Take a time and read documentation on [GROUP BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 2):

Your query returns the max ID for every unique combination of the other columns, so it’s behaving as expected.

If you only want the row whose ID is the max:

```
select
    ...
from mytable
where ID = (select max(ID) from mytable)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from [LAB_CULTURE_RESULT] where id = ( select MAX( id ) from [LAB_CULTURE_RESULT])
```

[How can I select the row with the highest ID in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881424/how-can-i-select-the-row-with-the-highest-id-in-mysql/20904650)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the last Id (primary key) inserted in any table then it is better to use *IDENT_CURRENT* to get the last inserted Id of any table.

```
 GO
 SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Table1')
 Go
```

Answer (score -1):

u should do like this :

```
select * from [LAB_CULTURE_RESULT] where id=(select max(id) from [LAB_CULTURE_RESULT] where order_id = 1900001265 
 and testid = 1100)
```